# Como fazer inner join no Jpa SpringBoot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
select m.id, m.nome, m.crm, e.descricao especialidade
              from medico m
              inner join especialidade e on e.id = m.especialidade_id
```

Cujo o retorno do banco de dados está assim:

```
'5', 'FLAVIO FIGUEIREDO', '5255', 'ORTOPEDIA'
'6', 'MARCELO BREVES', '1050', 'ORTOPEDIA'
'4', 'ANA HAOXOWELL', '5155', 'PEDIATRIA'
'1', 'ALBERTO SOUZA', '3215', 'CLINCA GERAL'
'2', 'MARIA DA SILVA', '1234', 'ENDOCRINOLOGIA'
'3', 'PAULO COSTA', '3210', 'CARDIOLOGIA'
```

Gostaria de fazer essa consulta utilizando Jpa e classe DTO,mas não estou conseguindo

Estou tentando fazer assim:

Minha classe DTO

**MedicoEspecialidadeDTO**

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MedicoEspecialidadeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String crm;
    private String descricao;    
}
```

**Repositório**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m.id, m.nome, m.crm, e.descricao especialidade" +
                   "  FROM medico m" +
                   "  INNER JOIN especialidade e ON e.id = m.especialidade_id")
    List<MedicoEspecialidadeDTO> findByMedicoEspecialidade();
```

Estou tento o seguinte erro ao tentar executar meu projeto

> antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: especialidade   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2620)
>
> 2020-10-11 17:43:55 WARN
> o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext -
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'medicoRepository': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
> method public abstract java.util.List
> com.vibesaude.saude.repository.MedicoRepository.findByMedicoEspecialidade()!
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'medicoRepository': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
> method public abstract java.util.List
> com.vibesaude.saude.repository.MedicoRepository.findByMedicoEspecialidade()!

**Entidades**

**Médico**

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "medico")
public class Medico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String crm;
    private String sexo;
    @Column(name = "dt_nascimento")
    private Date dtNascimento;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "especialidade_id",nullable=false)
    private Especialidade especialidade;

}
```

**Especialidade**

```
@Entity(name = "especialidade")
@Data
public class Especialidade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String descricao;
}
```

Comment: poderia adicionar  o código das entidades usadas na query?

Comment: Sim. Adicionei no final

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste tópico.Talvez te ajude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004996/unexpected-token-in-hql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer inner join com JPQL não é necessário comparar os ids, você poder fazer assim.

```
select m.id, m.nome, m.crm, e.descricao
from Medico m
inner join m.especialidade e
```

Caso queira que o seu resultado seja retornado em um DTO você precisará especificar o objeto de retorno na query,o DTO precisar possuir um construtor com os campos que queira retornar.

```
select NEW pacote.meu.dto.MedicoEspecialidadeDTO(m.id, m.nome, m.crm, e.descricao)
from Medico m
inner join m.especialidade e
```

A ordem dos parâmetros deve ser a mesma do construtor.

Comment: Isso que eu senti dúvida por tentei comparar

Comment: a resposta resolveu sua questão? @adventistaam

Comment: Tive esse problema: Error creating bean with name 'medicoRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.vibesaude.saude.repository.MedicoRepository.lista()!

Comment: tem que verificar se a ordem dos parâmetros no construtor e mesma da query e se os tipos de dados dos campos do dto e o mesmo das entidades.

Comment: Estou isso aqui `@AllArgsConstructor`

Comment: @adventistaam, o método que está com erro não é o que está na questão

Comment: Verdade, eu havia trocado o nome.... mas é a mesma função

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113995/discussion-between-jony-lima-and-adventistaam).